# Linux message sender and receiver execute error(repetition error)

Tags: c, linux

I worked in Linux. 
I only want to print the message on receiver when Sanders sends.
but, the receiver continues to output same message.

I exactly want to get message in receiver, only if sender sends message.
This code is my code. 
I try to conditional, but it's not easy. help

```
//Sender
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int fd; 
  char message[100];
  printf("Enter \"exit\"  to stop: \n");

  while(1)
  {
    fd=open("/home/control/work/io_dev",O_RDWR); //open file
    if (fd ==-1) {
        printf("Device open error"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    sleep(1);
    write(fd,message,sizeof(message));
    printf("Sender>>"); 
    fgets(message,sizeof(message),stdin);// input message
    write(fd,message, sizeof(message));//write on file
    if(strcmp(message,"exit\n")==0)
        break;
    write(fd,message,sizeof(message));

    close(fd); //file close
  }
}
```

```
//Receiver
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int fd;
  char message[100];

  while(1){
    sleep(1);
    fd=open("/home/control/work/io_dev",O_RDWR|O_CREAT); // open or create file
    if (fd == -1) { //when file open error occurs
      printf("Device open error");
      exit(1);
    }
    read(fd, message, sizeof(message));//read file
    sleep(1);//wait
    if(strcmp(message,"exit\n") ==0)//loop off
        break;
    if(message[0]!='\0'){
    printf("Received>> %s",message);//print
    }
    write(fd,message,sizeof(message));
    close(fd);//file close
    sleep(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Check what `read` returns!  <0 = Error, 0 = EOF, >0 number of bytes read. 2) `read` might return more or less than a line. You can't assume you got exactly one line. 3) Also, `read` won't add a NUL after what it reads, so `strcmp(message,"exit\n")` is not good.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Device open error");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr` and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling: `perror( "fopen failed" )` as that will perform both operations

Comment: in the receiver: regarding the calls to `sleep()`  1) completely not needed 2) 1..3 seconds is an eternity in a computer.  Suggest letting the execution be paced via the blocking calls to `read()`

Comment: in the receiver:  why opening/closing the file over and over and over?  Suggest moving the code to open the file and the code to close the file to before/after the loop

Comment: regarding: `fd=open("/home/control/work/io_dev",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666 );`  the call to `open()` could fail when the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the first "write(fd,message,sizeof(message));" in sender side.

Delete "if(message[0]!='\0')"in receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code, for `receiver`

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. avoids having to continually open/close the I/O device
5. echos what was actually received rather than the whole receiver buffer, much of which may contain trash
6. avoids the use of 'magic' numbers in the code

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_MSG_LEN 100

int main( void )
{
    int fd;
    char message[ MAX_MSG_LEN ];

    fd=open("/home/control/work/io_dev",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666 ); // open or create file
    if (fd == -1) 
    { //when file open error occurs
         printf("Device open error");
         exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {   
        ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, message, sizeof(message));//read file
        if( bytesRead <0 )
        {
            // handle error and exit
            perror( "read failed" );
            close( fd );
            break;
        }

        if( bytesRead == 0 )
        { // sender closed the connection
            // clean up and exit
            close( fd );
            break;
        }

        message[ bytesRead ] = '\0';

        if(strcmp(message,"exit\n") ==0)//loop off
            break;

        printf("Received>> %s",message);//print

        if( write(fd,message,strlen(message)) != strlen( message ) )
        {
            // handle incomplete message write
        }
    }
    close(fd);//file close
}
```

HOWEVER, if your trying to 'pace' the read/write operations with multiple readers and writers; then strongly suggest using a mutex to avoid any 'race' conditions and maybe even `mkfifo()` for creating the file.  Remember to (before exiting the program) to destroy the fifo.

If deciding to use a FIFO, then be sure to call `unlink( filename );` so the file will be destroyed when the program exits

If you want to keep the repeated open/close in the while() loop, then use O_EXCL rather than O_CREAT  so the separate programs cannot step on each other.